# Apply wordpress snippet for specific category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, e-commerce, code-snippets

I need to apply a snippet where the maximum variable price of woocommerce products is displayed but only in the category ID 29. I didn't manage to do this, so I leave you the code for the function without the category. It works for the max variable price. I hope someone can help me! Thank you very much.

```
 // define the woocommerce_variable_price_html callback 
function filter_woocommerce_variable_price_html( $wc_format_price_range, $instance ) { 
$index = strpos($wc_format_price_range, "&ndash; ");
$wc_format_price_range = substr($wc_format_price_range, $index+7);
//This will remove the first price by dividing the standard string with dash
//You may add a prefix like, $wc_format_price_range = "Max Price: $wc_format_price_range";
return $wc_format_price_range = "Max Price: $wc_format_price_range";; 
}; 
// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'filter_woocommerce_variable_price_html', 10, 2 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, $instance is $product, so we can use that to check if it belongs to category ID 29 first.

I'm using this reference: [WooCommerce Conditional Logic – Tags, Examples & PHP](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-conditional-logic-ultimate-php-guide) and you can see you can use the has_term() function to check if a given product belongs to a set category.

In your case, your code would become the following:

```
// define the woocommerce_variable_price_html callback 
function filter_woocommerce_variable_price_html( $wc_format_price_range, $instance ) { 

   // exit if product does not belong to cat 29
   if ( ! has_term( 29, 'product_cat', $instance->get_id() ) ) return $wc_format_price_range;

   $index = strpos($wc_format_price_range, "&ndash; ");
   $wc_format_price_range = substr($wc_format_price_range, $index+7);
   //This will remove the first price by dividing the standard string with dash
   //You may add a prefix like, $wc_format_price_range = "Max Price: $wc_format_price_range";
   return $wc_format_price_range = "Max Price: $wc_format_price_range";; 
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'filter_woocommerce_variable_price_html', 10, 2 
);
```